# nginx + uwsgi Standalone scripts

Tags: python, nginx, cgi, wsgi, uwsgi

I decided to use `uWSGI` to run Python on my website. I want to allow execution of standalone  Python scripts like http://domain.com/signup.py or so. Is there a possible way to do this? I searched for the solution carefully, but still didn't find anything.

Comment: you may also take a look at this http://wiki.nginx.org/NgxWSGIModule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish is running CGI scripts. So you have to use the uWSGI cgi plugin: https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/CGI.html

This is a general plugin that has nothing to do with python.